# How to make Range.Value have cell reference specific to local row vba

Tags: vba, reference, range, row, cell

I want to add a range, C2:E6, where the value for each row refers to that row's A and B cells. For example, C2, D2 and E2 should be equal to

"=A2*B3"

C3, D3 and E3 should be equal to

"=A3*B3"

etc. I can do a For loop, but it would be much easier if I could figure out how to do it using Range.Value. I'm fairly new to VBA, is there some way to do this that I'm just not familiar with? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: so all three should have the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Range("C2:E10").Formula = "=$A2*$B2"
Range("C2:E10").Value = Range("C2:E10").Value
```

Change the `10` to your final row.  Excel will change the row reference automatically.  Then replace the formula with the resultant value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the fórmula or just want values?

I create an example that keep the fórmula inside the cell, for a small range it work well but if you want something for 3000x3000 cells is better use a 2d array to keep the values until the end of the loop and after the loop ends you pass it to the worksheet.

```
Sub Example()

Dim celly As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C2:E6")


For Each celly In rng

    celly.FormulaLocal = "=A" & celly.Row & "*B3"

Next celly

End Sub
```